# C#: Open a Fullscreen process

Tags: c#

I'm creating a program that opens to applications (.exe). I can open one of them, that's a windowed application (samp.exe), but I can't open the other one (gta_sa.exe), that's a fullscreen application.

I don't know if using `Process.Start()` doesn't allow me to open it, but I guess it's not because of it.

Here's my code:

```
private void btnSA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(Properties.Settings.Default.SAPath);
}
```

The `Properties.Settings.Default.SAPath` is the file path (C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto San Andreas\gta_sa.exe)

Comment: Do you get an error message, or is it just that nothing happens?

Comment: @Nuno have you cross checked it whether this application is opening on double click?

Comment: @vbnet3d I click on the button and nothing happens. On the other side the other application I have executes normally

Comment: @Tanmay well, I haven't. How can I do that?

Comment: @Nuno Just open gta_sa.exe file normally by double clicking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why it wasn't working.

For some reason my computer didn't show up the game because of some configs. After reversing them I managed to open the game normally.

Thank you all for your answers!